# How do I merge/compare files ignoring order?

Tags: file, merge, compare

I have two properties files that are not the same and I need to find the differences. The second file is sorted by key.

Is there a tool that can help me with it? From what I've seen every merge tool cares very much about the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done it in bash on Linux by sorting both files and then merge them. If you are on Windows you could install Cygwin for running Linux programs.

However, I think you are best served by creating a small program to do it, probably takes you less time than learning to use Cygwin.

Edit: You could look at it as a small project to learn a new technology. I often use projects like these to learn things like Ruby or Python. Although it may not be accepted if it is at work.

Comment: If using Windows, skip Cygwin and use native tools. http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Sort one or both files.

Then run "diff".